# Google_AuthException [ 400 ]: Error fetching OAuth2 access token, message: 'invalid_grant'

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-api

The problem arises when I get the code and makes a request for a token. For authorization using code that works fine on other projects. I check Credentials in developer console and my config file. Attempts to connect the authorization from other sites and other accounts yielded nothing. I checked redirects, headers, but found nothing.

Comment: Do you have an example of the you are using for authentication?

Comment: I use kohana framework module for google auth. https://github.com/pocesar/googleapi-kohana

Answer (score 0):

$request = Google_Client::$io->makeRequest(new Google_HttpRequest('https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token', 'POST', array(), array(
          'code' => $_GET['code'],
          'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
          'redirect_uri' => $this->redirectUri,
          'client_id' => $this->clientId,
          'client_secret' => $this->clientSecret
      )));

This request return "Error fetching OAuth2 access token, message: 'invalid_grant'"